# References for Green's functions right focal boundary-value problem

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Could you please give me some references for the computation of a Green's function for a second-order right focal difference equation?
For this problem:
\begin{gather*}
\Delta^2 u(t)=f(t), \; t\in\{0,1,\dotsc,n\} \\
u(0)=\Delta u(n+1)=0
\end{gather*}
where
$\Delta u(t)=u(t+1)-u(t)$.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

See the book "Difference equations: an introduction with applications" by
Walter G Kelley and Allan C Peterson
Academic press, 2001